# ABAP AL11 directories not visible

Tags: networking, authorization, abap, transfer

I got a problem since the update on EHP8 for SAP.
We got many directories under the main directory "transfer.test/te11/" but since the update we can´t see the directory anymore if "S_DATASET" doesn´t have the entry in filename like this "transfer.test/te11*".

For some people the authorisation object "S_DATASET" contains the filename "transfer.test/te11/test*" but they don´t see anything neither the entry for the main directory nor the subdirector which they are authorisated in AL11.

Does somebody have an idea ? SU53, authorisation check, doesn´t through an error.

Greetz

Comment: If you don't see an authorization error in `SU53`, it means it's not related to the authorizations `S_DATASET`. I just checked with my system, I don't see authorization checks in AL11 to filter out directories. See notes [2811447 - Directory is missing in AL11 after system copy / upgrade / migration / kernel update](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2811447) and [2718329 - AL11 does not list all files/directories](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2718329).

Comment: Well the problem is, that `S_DATASET` FILENAME contains the AL11 path. If I change it to "transfer.test/te11*" the user can see everything also every other subdirectory but if I change it to "transfer.test/te11/test*" the user can´t see anything. It is since the EHP8 upgrade unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it's what you already said in your question. Did you check the SAP notes?

Comment: Yes, but they didn´t help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "solution" that we did was in the authorization object `S_DATASET` . There we could insert a value from...to and I did it with  from "transfer.test/te11" to "transfer.test/te11" and another value for "transfer.test/te11/test*" that  helped.